# What happens to an Android service when PowerManager.goToSleep is called?

Tags: android, android-service, android-wake-lock

I'm trying to figure out what happens to an android service when 
    PowerManager.goToSleep()
is called.

Say the device is asleep for x amount of time. When the device comes out of the sleep state, there are no LifeCycle methods like onPause() or onRestart() within a service that are used to notify the service of the change.

I know that according to the documentation, all WakeLocks are overridden, so does that imply that the service will be destroyed and not started again?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#goToSleep%28long%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so does that imply that the service will be destroyed and not started again?

No. It implies that the service is unchanged. All sleep mode does is stop the CPU.

Comment: Since the package manager revokes my DEVICE_POWER permission at runtime, I'm unable to execute PowerManager.goToSleep() .
My question arises out of the following

goToSleep() stops the CPU, then all the objects that were in execution prior to a call to goToSleep() must be: 

a) destroyed and on wake up the intents that started those objects sent again. 
 or 
b) saved in some manner so that their execution can be restored once the CPU starts again. 

I'm unable to figure out which one it is.

Comment: The closest way I can think of testing this is to start a service, whose onStartCommand() returns START_REDELIVER_INTENT, and forcibly stopping it while it is still executing. The service is then immediately scheduled for a restart, from which I can observe that onCreate() is called, implying that the service is being re-instantiated. 

Is calling goToSleep() going to cause behavior similar to this?

Comment: @Archit Joshi: "the package manager revokes my DEVICE_POWER permission at runtime" -- you never got that permission in the first place. "I'm unable to figure out which one it is." -- it is just kept in RAM. "Is calling goToSleep() going to cause behavior similar to this?" -- no.

Comment: Maybe I need to supply some context here. 
I'm writing a test program for a device, where I manually put the device into sleep and log a few conditions, and upon wake up, log some more. This has to be done in a service. Once I call goToSleep() for x milliseconds, I'd like to know from what point my service would start executing again, once the device emerges from sleep.
I'm aware that I need to aquire signature level permissions, which I don't have (yet), to be able to sucessfully call goToSleep().  
What method will begin execution when the device comes out of the sleep state?

Comment: @Archit Joshi: "What method will begin execution when the device comes out of the sleep state?" -- none. Or any. The fact that the device was in sleep state does not matter. The CPU picks up with the next instruction. Whatever would have happened next in the service without the sleep state will happen next when you wake up from sleep state. There are no lifecycle methods associated with the device falling asleep.

Comment: Hmmm. Well that makes my life a bit easier actually. Odd that there aren't any callbacks for that happening. Either way, this is the exact information I needed. Thanks a lot Mark!